# Why does the other function output the wrong values?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a root finding program. I'm already at this bug for hours. The code seems right to me, but the terminal output is wrong. And this newbie has a lot of arguments present in his functions. I hope you guys don't mind.

Yes, I've compiled the codes over and over again.

These are the troublesome lines. Below these are all the lines that I think are relevant. Instead of it outputting `exp(-x) - x` and `Newton-Raphson` respectively, it gives me `Restart selection` and `exp(-4*x) - x`.

```
printf("%25s:%20s\n", "Equation", a[eq-1].c_str());
printf("%25s:%20s\n", "Method", b[meth-1].c_str());
```

Here are the relevant variables in main().

```
vector<string> functName;
vector<string> methodName;
vector<string> advSettings;

int c_eq = 0;
int c_met = 0;
int c_settings = 0;
double c_guess1 = 0;
double c_guess2 = 0;

// defaults
int sigFigs = 6;
int iter = 1000;
int iterMode = 0;
int perIter = 0;
int plotMode = 0;

functName.push_back("exp(-x) - x");
functName.push_back("exp(-2*x) - x");
functName.push_back("exp(-3*x) - x");
functName.push_back("exp(-4*x) - x");

methodName.push_back("Newton-Raphson");
methodName.push_back("False Position");
methodName.push_back("Bisection");
methodName.push_back("Secant");

advSettings.push_back("Proceed with settings");
advSettings.push_back("Restart selection");
advSettings.push_back("Change advanced settings");
```

Here is the first function that outputs things properly.

```
template <typename inputType>
void basicInterface(const vector<string> &a,
                    const vector<string> &b,
                    int eq,
                    int meth,
                    inputType &root1,
                    inputType &root2)
{
    cout << "Input the corresponding number of your choice.\n";
    cout << "Choose an equation to solve:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        cout << "[" << i+1 << "] " << a[i] << endl;          // line of interest
    cout << " >>> ";
    inputCheck(eq,1,4);

    cout << "Choose a method to use:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
        cout << "[" << i+1 << "] " <<  b[i] << endl;         // line of interest
    cout << " >>> ";
    inputCheck(meth,1,4);

    // more stuff
}
```

The lines of interest output the following in my Terminal, which are correct.

```
[1] exp(-x) - x
[2] exp(-2*x) - x
[3] exp(-3*x) - x
[4] exp(-4*x) - x

[1] Newton-Raphson
[2] False Position
[3] Bisection
[4] Secant
```

This other function, which is supposed to show all stuff,

```
template <typename inputType>
void showSettings(  const vector<string> &a,
                    const vector<string> &b,
                    int eq,
                    int meth,
                    inputType root1,
                    inputType root2,
                    int sigs,
                    int showPerLoop,
                    int plotRoots,
                    int loopMode,
                    int minLoops)
{
    cout << "Requirements satisfied.\n";
    printf("%25s:%20s\n", "Equation", a[eq-1].c_str());
    printf("%25s:%20s\n", "Method", b[meth-1].c_str());
    if(meth-1 == 1)
        printf("%25s:%20f\n", "Initial Guess", root1);
    else
    {
        printf("%25s:%20f\n", "Initial Guess 1", root1);
        printf("%25s:%20f\n", "Initial Guess 2", root2);
    }
    printf("%25s:%20d\n", "Minimum Sig Figs", sigs);
    printf("%25s:%20d (1 if true)\n", "Show Root per Iteration", showPerLoop);
    printf("%25s:%20d (1 if true)\n", "Show Root Graph", plotRoots);
    printf("%25s:%20d (1 if true)\n", "Iteration Mode", loopMode);
    printf("%25s:%20d\n", "Minimum Iterations", minLoops);
}
```

almost gives perfect output.

```
                 Equation:   Restart selection        // where did these
                   Method:       exp(-4*x) - x        // come from?
          Initial Guess 1:            1.000000
          Initial Guess 2:            0.000000
         Minimum Sig Figs:                   6
  Show Root per Iteration:                   0 (1 if true)
          Show Root Graph:                   0 (1 if true)
           Iteration Mode:                   0 (1 if true)
       Minimum Iterations:                1000
```

The following are the lines I used to call the two functions.

```
    basicInterface( functName,
                    methodName,
                    c_eq,
                    c_met,
                    c_guess1,
                    c_guess2);

    showSettings(   functName,
                    methodName,
                    c_eq,
                    c_met,
                    c_guess1,
                    c_guess2,
                    sigFigs,
                    perIter,
                    plotMode,
                    iterMode,
                    iter);
```

Comment: To start with, don't mix old C-style output with the new C++ stream output. They use different buffers which might cause output to be scrambled. Probably not the case here, but remember it for the future. You can format output more flexible with [I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

Comment: When you say something's wrong. It is usually good to specify what does wrong mean. What do you expect and what you get. It is also useful to make sure its easy to spot with rather big walls of code. EDIT: Maybe it's my bad, but I think i got it after 3rd pass, and still not entirely sure.

Comment: @luk32 I made an edit. Look at the beginning of the post.

Comment: @solitude Yea thanks. The expected part is kinda important. Not even the indexes for the mixed vectors are ok. IMO the fastest way to go, is to see through any kind of debug if your indices and vectors passed to `showSettings` make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted a lot of code. But it seems these two lines produce your output.

```
printf("%25s:%20s\n", "Equation", a[eq-1].c_str());
printf("%25s:%20s\n", "Method", b[meth-1].c_str());
```

`eq` and `meth` are both 0. This causes access to the vectors at index -1. Use `at` instead of operator [] to check the passed bounds if unsure. `at` will throw an exception if the index is not valid; `operator []` will fail silently instead and produce UB.

Comment: I think it would be important to mention that the `at` method will throw an exception that has to be caught on index out of bounds. More specifically [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range).

Comment: I tried to provide every relevant thing at the start. Yes, those two. The thing is, initial eq and meth values are replaced by proper values before the invocation of `showSettings`. I also have an inputChecker to make sure the values are always within bounds.

Comment: @solitude This still looks kind of suspicios. Did you look into this part with a debugger or the `at` method to be 100% sure?

Comment: @user1781290 This is weird. I've never come across this one. Here's what it says after I used `at`. `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector
Abort trap: 6`

Comment: @solitude This means your index is actually not in the bounds of the vector, thus it threw an exception. Now you need to trace from where this bad index comes (EDIT: or if the vector was modified somewhere before)

Comment: @user1781290 I tried referencing `eq` and `meth` so that both things are modified but the compiler gave me a very big clutter of `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:`.

Comment: @solitude You can just print `eq` and `meth` to stdout for a fast check if they are sane.

Comment: @solitude Can't you use a debugger, this will simplify your problem largely. Also why are you substracting 1 from `eq` and `meth`, are they really 1-bound indices?

Comment: @luk32 There goes the `0`s

@user1781290 They're supposed to be a direct conversion from user input so I have to subtract 1 to make up for the zero index convention of containers. Working on the debugger thing

Comment: @solitude So if they are 0, chances are they are either not changed (maybe the change should happen in a function and they are not passed by-reference) or they are already decremented before. Good Hunting ;)

Comment: @solitude Well then you gotta find out why `c_eq` and `c_meth` are 0. The problem in in some else place in code. Maybe you didn't set it to proper values (sometimes can happen if you use similar variable names or copy-paste), or you already converted it to `0` based indexing upon reading or something.

Comment: @user1781290 @luk32 It seems I forgot to set the `eq` and `meth` parameters to pass by reference. The modifying functions were only looking at the copied `0`'s of `eq` and `meth`. This is a classic case of pass by reference/value fail by newbie. Sorry for the trouble. It works perfectly now.